Select columns of selected cells in VBA
I'm trying to select and delete a number of columns in Excel depending if they have certain values in the first row.
Code below. I pulled the function FindAll from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx.
Sub delete_unwanted_columns()

    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = FindAll(Range("1:1"), "p-value", xlValues, xlPart)
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng3 = FindAll(Range("1:1"), "type", xlValues, xlPart)

    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Union(rng2, rng3)
    End With

    Rng.Select
'    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection).EntireColumn.Select
'    Selection.Delete Shift:=Left

End Sub

This gives me this:

When I uncomment the second to last line I get this:

I would like it to select all the columns that start with "p-value" or "type", but it only selects the first 2. Why would this be and how can I fix?

rng.entirecolumn.delete Shift:=Left

@ScottCraner This didn't work for "Argument not optional" but I did Rng.EntireColumn.Select and then Selection.Delete. Thanks!

I have a function that does something similar using a Do While loop to check each cell until it hits a blank cell in my header row. Adapted for you, it looks like this:
Dim currentCol as Integer
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Do While Not Cells(1, i) = ""
        currentCol = Cells(1, i).Column
        findValue1 = "type"
        findValue2 = "p-value"

        If InStr(1, Left$(Cells(1, i), 4), findValue1) or InStr(1, Left$(Cells(1, i), 7), findValue2) ' Notice the "4" and the "7" used to limit how much of the cell's value to check... don't want it finding "type" or "p-value" anywhere but at the beginning
            Columns(currentCol).Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1 ' You only need to advance one column if you've deleted a column.
        End IF
    Loop
End With


Delete Range Columns Designated By Their Headers
Sub DeleteUnwantedColumns()
    
    Dim Begins() As Variant: Begins = Array("p-value", "type")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim frg As Range: Set frg = rg.Rows(1)
    Dim lcell As Range: Set lcell = frg.Cells(frg.Cells.Count)
    
    Dim urg As Range, fcell As Range, Begin As Variant, FirstColumn As Long
    
    For Each Begin In Begins
        Set fcell = frg.Find(Begin & "*", lcell, xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        If Not fcell Is Nothing Then
            FirstColumn = fcell.Column
            Do
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = fcell
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, fcell)
                End If
                Set fcell = frg.FindNext(fcell)
            Loop Until fcell.Column = FirstColumn
        End If
    Next Begin
    
    If urg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Columns had already been deleted!", vbExclamation
    Else
        Intersect(rg, urg.EntireColumn).Delete xlToLeft
        MsgBox "Columns deleted.", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub

